# DST UIDatePicker issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, date

Problem that occurs to me:

> In the case of the United States where a one-hour shift occurs at
>   02:00 local time, in spring the clock jumps forward from the last
>   moment of 01:59 standard time to 03:00 DST and that day has 23 hours,
>   whereas in autumn the clock jumps backward from the last moment of
>   01:59 DST to 01:00 standard time, repeating that hour, and that day
>   has 25 hours.[37] A digital display of local time does not read 02:00
>   exactly at the shift to summer time, but instead jumps from 01:59:59.9
>   forward to 03:00:00.0.

And `UIDatePicker` is not given opportunity to set 02:00:00 time, when DST occurs. How it is possible to fix in `UIDatePicker` to be able to chose that time?

Comment: Just wondering why do you want to let the user to choose that time?

Comment: @zcui93 It is connected with time tracking of the intervals that users can edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSTimeZone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTimeZone/daylightSavingTimeOffset) is an abstract class that defines the behavior of time zone objects. Time zone objects represent geopolitical regions. Daylight Savings is also managed with that class. It can be done in one of the ways:

- systemTimeZone: 
  The time zone currently used by the system. If the current time zone cannot be determined, returns the GMT time zone.
- defaultTimeZone: 
  The default time zone for the current application. If no default time zone has been set, this method invokes systemTimeZone and returns the system time zone.
- localTimeZone: 
  An object that forwards all messages to the default time zone for the current application. The local time zone represents the current state of the default time zone at all times.

with the localTimeZone class method, you can get a relative time zone object that decodes itself to become the default time zone on any computer on which it finds itself.